# Exception occurs performing aggregate queries on x64 platform

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

When running a query using aggregates I receive the following exception:

```
Microsoft.Azure.Documents.BadRequestException: 
{"Errors":["Cross partition query only supports 'VALUE <AggreateFunc>' for aggregates."]} 
---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A0B00
```

My query code is:

```
var store = "1234";
var sumResults = client.CreateDocumentQuery(
UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri("my-data-db", "my-collection"),
$"SELECT SUM(t.totalAmount) FROM t where t.siteData.siteID = '{store}'");
```

It took me a while to figure out this works fine when the build platform is set to x86 but fails when set to x64.

I'm using the latest version of the package 1.12.2

Any ideas on how to make the x64 version work?

Comment: Have you tried modifying, as suggested in the error, to use `VALUE`? (e.g. `SELECT VALUE SUM(t.totalAmount) FROM t where t.siteData.siteID = '{store}'`

Comment: Also - just to clarify - you're using the emulator?

Comment: No I am not using the emulator, I am using the live service (East US).

Comment: Why would it need changing on x86 vs x64 builds, surely it should work the same on both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to your description, I used [Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB 1.12.2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB) to test the similar query both on DocomentDB Emulator and Azure DocumentDB. After some trials, I found this issue only occurs when you are using the SQL aggregate functions (e.g. COUNT, MIN, MAX, SUM, and AVG) against DocomentDB Emulator (my current version is 1.11.136.2) and your project is built on x64.

As this official [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/planet-scale-aggregates-with-azure-documentdb/) mentioned about aggregates with Azure DocumentDB:

> Aggregate support has been rolled out to all DocumentDB production datacenters. You can start running aggregate queries against your existing DocumentDB accounts or provision new DocumentDB accounts via the SDKs, REST API, or the Azure Portal. You must however download the latest version of the [SDKs](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/documentdb/documentdb-sdk-dotnet) in order to **perform cross-partition aggregate queries** or **use LINQ aggregate operators** in .NET.

I assumed that you could leverage aggregates with LINQ as follows:

```html
var amount=client.CreateDocumentQuery<DocEntity>("/dbs/{your-db-id}/colls/{your-collection-id}",
     new FeedOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = -1 })
      .Where(r => r.siteID == "1234")
      .Sum(r=>r.totalAmount);
```

We could find the above query would generate the following query:

`{"query":"SELECT VALUE Sum(root[\"totalAmount\"]) FROM root WHERE (root[\"siteID\"] =\"1234\") "}`

For more details, you could refer to this [tutorial](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/planet-scale-aggregates-with-azure-documentdb/).

Comment: Thanks for investigating!  I am not using the emulator and get this error when running against the production service (East US).  I will try altering my query to use the VALUE statement, however my confusion and issue lay with the difference in behaviour between the x86 and x64 platforms.

Comment: Have you solved this issue after using `VALUE <AggreateFunc>` for aggregates? I assumed that it's a Azure issue, I would report this issue, you could also add your feedback [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb).

Comment: Just tested it, and using `SELECT VALUE SUM` works on both x86/x64.  I will provide the feedback as suggested.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put Value in your query, like this

SELECT VALUE COUNT(1) 
FROM C